# After return parent::_prepareCollection() store filter not working in product collection

Tags: magento2

I have override `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser` Block and I have added Store filter to Product Collection in `_prepareCollection` function. I am returning **parent::_prepareCollection();** in my override block but it is not filtering my product as product wise. If I return **$this->setCollection($collection);** than it working fine but if I return  **parent::_prepareCollection();** than it does not filter my product collection.

Anyone have idea why this does not work when I return `parent::_prepareCollection().`

Comment: Can you please add code in question?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the parent block, the `prepareCollection` method creates new collection from factory and set it using `setCollection` method:

```
/**
 * Prepare products collection, defined collection filters (category, product type)
 *
 * @return Extended
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
    $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setStoreId(0)->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    if ($categoryId = $this->getCategoryId()) {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
        if ($category->getId()) {
            // $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
            $productIds = $category->getProductsPosition();
            $productIds = array_keys($productIds);
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
        }
    }

    if ($productTypeId = $this->getProductTypeId()) {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', $productTypeId);
    }

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

So, if you adding the store id filter to the collection and than call a parent method it will overwrite you collection, and by this way your filters has gone.

Better way will be first call the parent method, then add your filters and call the `setCollection` method one more time.

It will be look like this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    // Create collection in general way
    parent::_prepareCollection();

    // Get this collection
    $collection = $this->getCollection();

    // Add your filter here
    // Add your filter here
    // Add your filter here

    // Update stored collection
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return $this;
}
```